# filter get_attribute for item results

Tags: python, selenium, get, attributes

Currently I'm using get_attribute to get all the instances of data-id on the page as soon as they load. But what I'm trying to figure out is how I could filter out some of these results. Particularly the ones with certain values for their data-type attribute. Is there anyway I could do this?

> ids = [item.get_attribute('data-id') for item in WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-id]")))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a if condition to your list comprehension :

```
if item.get_attribute('data-type') == "yourValue"
```

It would then look like this:

```
els = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-id]")))
ids = [item.get_attribute('data-id') 
       for item in els if item.get_attribute('data-type') == "yourValue"]
```

EDIT:
The value of item.get_attribute('data-type') is not "Knife" but "Knife ". (space at the end)

Solution1: Remove the whitespaces using strip():

```
if item.get_attribute('data-type').strip() == "Knife"
```

Solution2: use in

```
 if "Knife" in item.get_attribute('data-type')
```

Solution3: add a space!

```
if item.get_attribute('data-type') == "Knife "
```

EDIT2:
If you want to match multiple values use:

```
accepted_type = ("Knife", "Knife2",...)
if item.get_attribute('data-type').strip() in accepted_type
```

Comment: Hmm seemed like it would work but for some reason when I go to print the results I'm getting [].

Comment: That would mean your condition is never met, can you share the html code you are trying to achieve this on?

Comment: Posted my script. Maybe that will give you better context.

Comment: Next time, don't post your script as an answer but edit your question!
I have edited my answer with my finding

Comment: Oh my. I guess I should have pulled my Element inspect over more cause it went onto a new line and I didn't see the space. Smh. Thank you. Could I add multiple values to that like a list?

Comment: Appreciate the help! I have one more question if you wouldn't mind. How would I be able to pull the text in this h3 tag? Since it doesn't have a class or id.

`<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:75%%">
     <h3 style="color:gray" title="Tradable After Mar 16, 2019 (07:00:00) GMT">Karambit | Doppler</h3>
     <div class="qty Covert">Covert</div>`

Comment: Try with the css_selector: ```[title*="Tradable After"]```. Then use the selenium property ```text``` to retrieve the value

Comment: Unfortunately only some results have that title so I switched to XPATH but when ever I try to get the result it prints out the element info and not the value. And when I try to get the text value with .text() it doesn't return anything at all.
`name = WebDriverWait(driver,0).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]")))`

Comment: Finally. I've spent literally the last 3 hours trying to figure this out. I had to have tried like 50 different things. Doesn't help half the topics on this are using JS or some other language.